# Need to delay javascript execution, but setTimeout is proving problematic

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Thank you for taking the time to help me.

I am writing a game where an animated train icon moves along a given path to a destination, pausing at waypoints along the way. This is intended to give the impression of animation.

The game is coded in Facebook Javascript. I need to find a way to make the train icon pause for 1 second before moving on to the next waypoint. I hoped to find a function that would allow me to pause script execution for one second, but nothing like that seems to exist in JS. So I tried setTimeout, but my primary problem with this is twofold:

1. I need to pass an array into the callback function as an argument, and I can't figure out how to make setTimeout do this.
2. I finally succeeded in using setTimeout to execute my train animation code for 5 waypoints (I overcame the issue in 1 by using global variables). Unfortunately, it appears that all five calls to setTimeout got queued almost simultaneously, which resulted in waiting one second for the first setTimeout to fire, thenn they all fired at once ruining the illusion of train animation.

I've been battling this problem for six hours straight. It would be wonderful if someone could help me find a solution. Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
function myEventMoveTrainManual(evt, performErrorCheck) {
      if(mutexMoveTrainManual == 'CONTINUE') {
        var ajax = new Ajax();
        var param = {};
        if(evt) {
          var cityId = evt.target.getParentNode().getId();
          var param = { "city_id": cityId };
        }
        ajax.responseType = Ajax.JSON;
        ajax.ondone = function(data) {
            var actionPrompt = document.getElementById('action-prompt');
            actionPrompt.setInnerXHTML('<span><div id="action-text">'+
              'Train en route to final destination...</div></span>');
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              statusFinalDest = data[i]['status_final_dest'];
               //pause(1000);
               gData = data[i];
               setTimeout(function(){drawTrackTimeout()},1000);
              if(data[i]['code'] == 'UNLOAD_CARGO' && statusFinalDest == 'ARRIVED') {
                unloadCargo();
              } else if (data[i]['code'] == 'MOVE_TRAIN_AUTO' || data[i]['code'] == 'TURN_END') {
                //moveTrainAuto();
              } else {
                // handle error 
              }
              mutexMoveTrainManual = 'CONTINUE';
            }  
        }
        ajax.post(baseURL + '/turn/move-train-final-dest', param);
      }

}


function drawTrackTimeout() {
  var trains = [];
  trains[0] = gData['train'];
  removeTrain(trains);
  drawTrack(gData['y1'], gData['x1'], gData['y2'], gData['x2'], '#FF0', trains);
  gData = null;
}
```

Comment: Just an assumption coz there is no sample code, Are you calling any function inside array, If so use set time out inside the array

Comment: Some code examples would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Typically this would be done by creating an object (say called *myTrain*) that has all its own data and methods, then call a *myTrain.run* mehod that looks to see where the train is. If it's between two stations, it calls itself with *setTimeout* and say a 50ms delay. When it reaches a station, it calls itself in 1000ms, creating a 1 second pause at the station.

If you queue the *setTimeouts* all at once, you run the risk of them all being delayed by some other process, then all running at once.

Hey, bit of fun (careful of wrapping). Needed a bit of practice with good 'ole prototype inheritance:

```
<!-- All the style stuff should be in a rule -->
<div style="position: relative; border: 1px solid blue;">
  <div id="redTrain"
   style="width:10px;height:10px;background-color:red; position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

// Train constructor
function Train(id) {
  this.element = document.getElementById(id);
  this.timerId;
}

// Methods
// Trivial getPos function
Train.prototype.getPos = function() {
  return this.element.style.left;
}

// Trivial setPos function
Train.prototype.setPos = function(px) {
  this.element.style.left = parseInt(px,10) + 'px';
}

// Move it px pixels to the right
Train.prototype.move = function(px) {
  this.setPos(px + parseInt(this.getPos(),10));
}

// Recursive function using setTimeout for animation
// Probably should accept a parameter for lag, long lag
// should be a multiple of lag
Train.prototype.run = function() {

  // If already running, stop it
  // so can interrupt a pause with a start
  this.stop();

  // Move the train
  this.move(5);

  // Keep a reference to the train for setTimeout
  var train = this;

  // Default between each move is 50ms
  var lag = 50;

  // Pause for 1 second each 100px
  if (!(parseInt(this.getPos(),10) % 100)) {
    lag = 1000;
  }

  train.timerId = window.setTimeout( function(){train.run();}, lag);

}

// Start should do a lot more initialising
Train.prototype.start = function() {
  this.run();
}

// Stops the train until started again
Train.prototype.stop = function() {
  if (this.timerId) {
    clearTimeout(this.timerId);
  }
}

// Set back to zero
Train.prototype.reset = function() {
  this.stop();
  this.setPos(0);
}

// Initialise train here
var myTrain = new Train('redTrain');

</script>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<button onclick="myTrain.start();">Start the train</button>
<button onclick="myTrain.stop();">Stop the train</button>
<button onclick="myTrain.reset();">Reset the train</button>
```

Comment: Hi Rob. Your prototype object looks like it would work. Unfortunately, Facebook JS does not support prototype.

Answer (score 0):

To pass arguments, this might help you:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    (function(arg1, arg2) {
        // you can use arg1 / arg2 here
    })('something', 123);
}, 1000);
```

Or, if you use a defined function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    someFunction('something', 123);
}, 1000);
```

It basically starts a timeout; after one second the function is invoked with the specified arguments.

Answer (score 0):

How about using OO principles to simplify the problem? Create an "object" Train which has the following methods:

```
//train obj
function Train(){
   this.isOnWaypoint = function(){
     return calculateIsWayPoint()
   }

}

//main logic
var train = new Train()
var doneWaiting = false
var doneWaitingTimeout = undefined
var gameLoop = setInterval(1000,function(){
   ...
   if(train.isOnWaypoint() && !doneWaiting){
     if(doneWaitingTimeout == undefined){
       setTimeOut(5000,function(){
         doneWaiting = true
         doneWaitingTimeout = undefined
       })
     }
   }
   ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I finally came up with:

```
function drawTrackTimeout() {
  if(gData != null && gIndex < gData.length) {
    var trains = [];
    trains[0] = gData[gIndex]['train'];
    removeTrain(trains);
    drawTrack(gData[gIndex]['y1'], gData[gIndex]['x1'], gData[gIndex]['y2'], gData[gIndex]['x2'], '#FF0', trains);

    statusFinalDest = gData[gIndex]['status_final_dest'];
    if(statusFinalDest == 'ARRIVED') {
      unloadCargo();
    } else if (gData[gIndex]['code'] == 'MOVE_TRAIN_AUTO' || gData[gIndex]['code'] == 'TURN_END') {
      //moveTrainAuto();
    } else {
      // handle error 
    }
    gIndex++;
  } else {
    clearInterval(gIntid);
    gIntid = null;
    gData = null;
    gIndex = 0;
  }
}


function myEventMoveTrainManual(evt, performErrorCheck) {
//debugger;
      if(mutexMoveTrainManual == 'CONTINUE') {
        var ajax = new Ajax();
        var param = {};
        if(evt) {
          var cityId = evt.target.getParentNode().getId();
          var param = { "city_id": cityId };
        }
        ajax.responseType = Ajax.JSON;
        ajax.ondone = function(data) {
            var actionPrompt = document.getElementById('action-prompt');
            actionPrompt.setInnerXHTML('<span><div id="action-text">'+
              'Train en route to final destination...</div></span>');
            gData = data;
            gIndex = 0;            
            gIntid = setInterval(function(){drawTrackTimeout()},1000);              
        }
        ajax.post(baseURL + '/turn/move-train-final-dest', param);
      }
}
```